# scala find the max value in a list of lists

Tags: scala

so I'm currently learning scala and found a problem:
I have a List of lists

```
List(
  List(8, 9, 10, 9, 8), 
  List(12, 9, 12, 8, 7), 
  List(12, 3, 12, 3, 2)
)
```

and want to find the max value
for example:

```
List(12, 9, 12, 9, 8)
```

How can I achieve that result?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work? My advice, look at the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) you literally only need two methods.

Comment: Are you trying to find the max value of each list or the max value at the same indexes in each list? Your sample output appears to be the max at the same index in each list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the max value at the same index in each list you can `tranpose` the list of lists then find the `max` for the transposed list.

This example straight from the Scala docs shows how `tranpose` works:

```
val xs = List(
           Set(1, 2, 3),
           Set(4, 5, 6)).transpose
 xs == List(
         List(1, 4),
         List(2, 5),
         List(3, 6))
```

Now do the same with your data and takes the max of the transposed lists:

```
val xss: List[List[Int]] = List(List(8, 9, 10, 9, 8), List(12, 9, 12, 8, 7), List(12, 3, 12, 3, 2))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
scala> xss.transpose.map(xs => xs.max)
val res3: List[Int] = List(12, 9, 12, 9, 8)
```